# How can i send Bundle Array value to another activity in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bundle

How can i send Bundle Array value  to another activity in android?

I have a class(sun.java).It's generate bundle type array.I need Bundle type array in String format in another actvity.

Help me

Thanks in advance

Sun.java class`enter

```
Intent intent=new Intent(PaymentPageActvity.this,CancelPaymentActivity.class);
                             Bundle b=new Bundle();
                             b.putBundle("inErrorMessage",inResponse);
                            Log.i("Error","onTransactionFailure :"+inErrorMessage);
                            Log.i("Error","onTransactionFailure :"+inResponse);

                            //intent.putExtras(inResponse);
                             //app.getLogger().error("Transaction Success :" + inResponse);

                            intent.putExtras(b);

                            startActivity(intent);
```

seconActivity is

```
  Bundle b=CancelPaymentActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
        Bundle array=b.getBundle("inErrorMessage");

        Log.i("array",""+array);
```

In logcat i got this value

```
onTransactionFailure :Bundle[{INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=Retail, payt_STATUS=1, ORDER_ID=FCF440, CHANNEL_ID=WAP, CUST_ID=48, ORDER_PHONE=7428453915, REQUEST_TYPE=DEFAULT, ORDER_EMAIL=singhamit1632@gmail.com, MID=klbGlV59135347348753, THEME=merchant, TXN_AMOUNT=8.0, WEBSITE=paytm, CHECKSUMHASH=PM5h/19blmHQyxBe2EDkMIi/Xqt5u3uijNMdWLJVzU60co6zhoHqmmFScNZaNVhwqrIm4kd2R6fEaROhFr9xsKtG96MIkymqkhtQ08DG6zQ=}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You put it in the Extras of the Intent you use to start the Activity. Check out the Google Docs for the Intent Class

Comment: Is it the full log? Do you get the Bundle or what?

Comment: so what about the toString() method of your bundle doesnt this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can send `string[]` or `ArrayList<String>` through bundle object as below

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("STRING_ARRAY", yourStringArray);
bundle.putStringArrayList("STRING_ARRAY_LIST", stringArrayList);
Intent intent =new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Hope this helps